# Oracle: Fastest Way in PL/SQL to See if Value Exists: List, VARRAY, or Temp Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

**UPDATE** View the edits if you care to see the long original question.  This is the clearer short version of the question...

I need to see if `GroupA` (not always `GroupA`, this changes each loop iteration) exists in a [list,varray,temp table, whatever] of 200 or so groups.  How I store those 200 groups is totally in my control.  But I want to store them in a construct  that lends itself to the FASTEST "existence" checking because I will have to check this list MANY times within a loop against different values (not always `GroupA`).  So whats fastest in PL/SQL, checking a list...

`IF 'GroupA' IN ('GroupA','GroupB') THEN...`

or checking a VARRAY using MEMBER OF...

```
IF 'GroupA' MEMBER OF myGroups THEN
```

or checking a VARRAY this way...

```
FOR i IN myGroups.FIRST .. myGroups.LAST
LOOP
    IF myGroups(i) = 'GroupA' THEN
        v_found := TRUE;
        EXIT;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

or checking associative arrays...
`will test this tomorrow`

**UPDATE: FINAL RESULTS OF TESTING FROM EVERYONE'S SUGGESTIONS**
Thanks all.
I ran these tests, looped 10 million times and the commas separated string using a `LIKE` seemed to be the fastest so I guess the points have to go to @Brian McGinity (the times are in the comments below).  But since the times were all so close it probably doesn't matter which method I go with.  I think I'll go with the `VARRAY MEMBER OF` method since I can load the array with a single line of code (bulk collect) instead of having to loop a cursor to build a string (thanks @Wernfried for bringing `MEMBER OF` to my attention)...

comma separated list, example: ,GroupA,GroupB,GroupC,...around 200 groups... (list made by looping a cursor)

```
FOR i IN 1 .. 10000000 loop
    if myGroups like '%,NONE,%' then
        z:=z+1;
    end if;
end loop;
--690msec
```

same commas separated list (list made by looping a cursor)...

```
FOR i IN 1 .. 10000000 loop
    if instr(myGroups, ',NONE,') > 0 then   
        z:=z+1;
    end if;
end loop;
--818msec
```

varray, same 200 groups (varray made by bulk collect)...

```
FOR i IN 1 .. 10000000 loop
    IF 'NONE' MEMBER of myGroups THEN
        z:=z+1;
    end if;
end loop;
--780msec
```

associative array method suggested by @Yaroslav Shabalin (assoc. array made by looping a cursor)...

```
FOR i IN 1 .. 10000000 loop
    if (a_values('NONE') = 1) then
        z:=z+1;
    end if;
end loop;
--851msec
```

Comment: Why sequentially processes? why not mass update a temp table to Y when a join exists between two tables.  1 by 1 processing is where a bottle neck is, it's only compounded by having to do a sub query within the loop.  RDBMs's processes sets of data much more efficiently than one by one activities.

Comment: This query in question that has to be checked inside the loop cannot be joined with the main query that is being looped because there is a function that has to happen in between the two and the functions does other queries to get what is needed for the query in question.  It is not a data structure I created.  I wish it could be redesigned but it can't.  I have to work with what I got on this one.

Comment: @gfrobenius, the fastest way it to keep this in oracle and not call a function. If you need the pgroup as a list and you also want to know if the user is a member of the group, than use 1 query and return 2 columns: theGroupList, isInGroup_YN

Comment: @BrianMcGinity I'm not calling a function.  I'm basically asking "which type of storage lends itself to the fastest existence check"? Because I can store these groups however I want, and I only do that once, but the existence check will happen many times within a loop.

Comment: Can you store them in a table like: userid, group?  1 row per userid/group.  And then query the table like any other indexed query.  That will be faster than storing them inline as: userid, csv_grouplist

Comment: @BrianMcGinity I don't think you're understanding the problem.  Putting a query in the loop would be the slowest way.  It's only around 100-200 values, so storing them in a [list,varray,whatever] then using pl/sql to do all my checks within a massive loop would be faster.  I'm trying to find out which of those is the fastest.

Comment: I am starring to see the picture here... Yeah, if you are already in plsql, switching context out to sql 200x would be slower. Usually data comes from a table at some point, that was why I suggesting to keep things in sql.

Comment: Very interesting results!!!! I was expecting instr to be the fastest.

Comment: Plus 1 -- great exercise and great result details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is myGroup a varray?   If it is a string try something like:

```
select 1
  from dual
 where 'abc,NONE,def' like '%,NONE,%'
```

It is hard to follow the constraints you're working under... If at all possible, do everything inside of sql and it will be faster.

### Update:

So if you're already in a plsql unit and wanted to stay in a plsql unit then the logic above would go something like this:

```
declare
    gp varchar2(200) := 'abc,def,NONE,higlmn,op';
  begin
    if ','||gp||',' like '%,NONE,%' then
      dbms_output.put_line('y');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('n');
    end if;
  end;
```

if this itself is in a loop then, make the list once as:

```
declare
    gp varchar2(200)  := 'abc,def,NONE,higlmn,op';
    gp2 varchar2(200) := ',' || gp || ',';
  begin
    if g2 like '%,NONE,%' then
      dbms_output.put_line('y');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('n');
    end if;
  end;
```

Also try instr which is probably faster than like:

```
  declare
    gp varchar2(200) := ',abc,def,NONE,hig,';
  begin
    if instr(gp, ',NONE,') > 0 then
      dbms_output.put_line('y');
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('n');
    end if;
  end;
```

I have no idea if this faster than the other solutions mentioned (it stands a good chance), it is something else to try.

Comment: I need to see if `GroupA` exists in a [list,varray,temp table, whatever] of 200 or so groups.  How I store those 200 groups is totally in my control.  But I want to store them in a construct  that lends itself to the FASTEST "existence" checking because I will have to check this list MANY times within a loop against different values (not always `GroupA`).  Make sense?

Comment: I still need clarification... Are you trying to decide if you want to store the groups in a table as:  userid, csv_group_member_list where each user has 1 row or in a table as: userid, single_group where 1 user will have many rows (1 for each group)

Comment: I don't want to store in a table because then I would have to query the database each loop iteration.  I want to store them in some pl/sql datatype, whichever datatype has the fastest "existence" checking.  I updated the original question.  See the top part.

Answer (score 3):

I did not get your full question but perhaps this function helps you: 
[MEMBER Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52115)

```
WHERE 'groupA' MEMBER of myGroups
```

Comment: Ah, that's a shorter way of checking the VARRAY, I like that.  So I can do this... `IF 'GroupA' MEMBER of myGroups THEN...`  BUT, is that faster than `IF 'GroupA' IN myGroups THEN...` if myGroups contains data like `'GroupA','GroupB','GroupC'...` That is the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [associative arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99969) also formerly known as "index-by tables"? Associative arrays indexed by string are optimized for efficient lookup by implicitly using the B*-tree organization of the values. It is PL/SQL equivalent to hash tables in other programming languages.

For example if you define an array as:

```
type t_values is table of number index by varchar2(20);
```

Then assign `GroupA` etc. to keys and `1` to each respective value:

```
a_values t_values;
for c_cursor in (select ...)
loop
 a_value(c_cursor.group_name) := 1;
end loop;
```

When you try to access the value for non-existent index, you will get null. Whereas for any real index you have `1` returned;

```
(a_value('GroupA') = 1) => TRUE
(a_value('Some_not_existent_index') IS NULL) => TRUE
```

Comment: I do use associative array in other areas.  I did not consider it for this because I figured it would be overkill since I don't need NAME/VALUE.  But I didn't think of just ignoring the values.  I'll test this tomorrow when I get back to the office.