# add n working days including custom holiday list in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to find the 'n'th business day in oracle plsql function which should exclude weekends and custom list of holidays. I got something like this however unable to fit the custom holiday logic in here,

```
create or replace function add_n_working_days ( 
  start_date date, working_days pls_integer
) return date as
  end_date date := start_date;
  counter  pls_integer := 0;
begin

  if working_days = 0 then
    end_date := start_date;
  elsif to_char(start_date, 'fmdy') in ('sat', 'sun') then
    end_date := next_day(start_date, 'monday');
  end if;

  while (counter < working_days) loop
    end_date := end_date + 1;
    if to_char(end_date, 'fmdy') not in ('sat', 'sun') then
      counter := counter + 1;
    end if;
  end loop;

  return end_date;

end add_n_working_days;
/
```

I have the custom holiday list in a different table which can be extracted using the sql

```
select holidays from holiday_table
```

I tried adding elsif condition with a sub query but that is not supported

```
if to_char(end_date, 'fmdy') not in ('sat', 'sun') then
      counter := counter + 1;
elsif to_char(end_date, 'YYYYMMDD') in (select holidays from holiday_table) then 
      counter := counter + 1;
end if;
```

Comment: *I need to find the 'n'th business day* Does some value of this `n` which will never be exceeded exists?

Comment: if your holiday list (i.e. number of rows in holiday_table) is not very long, bulk collect it into a pl/sql table, and then you can check if end_date is there by using MEMBER OF look at [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241680/oracle-fastest-way-in-pl-sql-to-see-if-value-exists-list-varray-or-temp-tabl)

Answer (score 0):

I will try with counting the number of weekend days with a similar loop:

```
WHILE (v_copy > 0) LOOP
    end_date := end_date + 1;

    IF to_char(end_date, 'fmdy') IN ('sat', 'sun') THEN
         end_date := end_date + 1;
    ELSE
        v_copy := v_copy - 1;  
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
```

And then after the looping process you can count the number of holidays in the table which are after the `start_date` and `end_date` and not in `('sat', 'sun')`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_custom_cnt 
 FROM holiday_table 
  WHERE to_char(holidays, 'fmdy') not in ('sat', 'sun') AND 
     holidays BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Now add this number to your `end_date` and you will get the date of the nth business day. Of course before returning check if the new `end_date` is in `('sat', 'sun')`.

```
end_date := end_date + v_custom_cnt;

IF to_char(holidays, 'fmdy') in ('sat', 'sun') THEN
  end_date := next_day(end_date, 'monday');
END IF;
```

Finally the `end_date` is the date of the nth working day.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_n_working_days ( 
  start_date DATE,
  working_days PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN DATE AS

  end_date DATE := start_date;
  counter  PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  v_copy PLS_INTEGER := working_days;

  v_custom_cnt INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN

  IF working_days = 0 THEN
    end_date := start_date;
  ELSIF to_char(start_date, 'fmdy') IN ('sat', 'sun') THEN
    end_date := next_day(start_date, 'monday');
  END IF;

  WHILE (v_copy > 0) LOOP
    end_date := end_date + 1;

    IF to_char(end_date, 'fmdy') IN ('sat', 'sun') THEN
         end_date := end_date + 1;
    ELSE
        v_copy := v_copy - 1;  
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO  v_custom_cnt
    FROM holiday_table
  WHERE to_char(end_date, 'fmdy')  NOT IN ('sat', 'sun') 
    AND holidays BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;

  end_date := end_date + v_custom_cnt;

  IF to_char(end_date, 'fmdy') IN ('sat', 'sun') THEN
    end_date := next_day(start_date, 'monday');
  END IF;  


  RETURN end_date;

END add_n_working_days;
```

**It is not 100% tested**

Answer (score 0):

Different approach: create a table that only lists business day and take nth value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_n_working_days ( 
  start_date DATE, working_days PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN DATE AS
  l_end_date DATE := start_date;
  l_counter  pls_integer := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT 
    business_day 
    INTO l_end_date
  FROM 
  (
    WITH 
    dates AS
      (SELECT start_date + level - 1  as dt FROM dual CONNECT BY level < 100)
    ,weekdates AS
    (SELECT dt as weekday FROM dates WHERE TO_CHAR(dt,'fmdy') NOT IN ('sat','sun'))
    ,business_days AS
    (
    SELECT weekday as business_day FROM weekdates
    MINUS
    SELECT holiday FROM so_holidays 
    )
    SELECT business_day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) as rn from business_days
  )
  WHERE rn = working_days + 1;
  RETURN l_end_date;
END add_n_working_days;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL is set orientated so start thinking in terms of sets NOT iteration (no loops). Assuming you can designate a maximum number of days to be tested you can get what you want with a single simple query.

```
create or replace function add_n_working_days ( 
  start_date date, working_days pls_integer
) return date as
  working_date_ot date;
begin
    with date_list as (select trunc(start_date) + level - 1 tdate 
                 from dual 
                connect by level <= 5*working_days  
               )  
    select tdate
      into working_date_ot
      from ( select tdate, row_number() over(order by tdate) date_num
               from date_list
              where to_char(tdate,'fmdy') not in ('sat','sun') 
                and not exists 
                   (select null 
                      from holiday_dates
                     where trunc(holiday_date) = tdate
                   )
            )                  
    where date_num = working_days;

    return working_date_ot; 
end add_n_working_days;
```

**How it works:**
The function assumes the desired date exists within 5 times the number of days requested. So if 10 business hence are requested the resulting date will be within 50 days (that would be a whole lot of holidays if not).

The date_list CTE builds a list of potential dates out to the identified limit.  
The sub select in the main filters the generated list eliminating Sat and Sun. It then probes the holiday table for the remaining dates and eliminating any any date in the table.  
Remaining dates are numbered based on ascending value.  
The main outer select then chooses the date number matching the working_days specified.

No Looping required. Just my .02 cents worth.